# 'Le faltan tamaños'

Tags: modismos, méxico, significado

Estaba escuchando un podcast de la BBC acerca del auge en la economia industrial en Mexico y en una parte estaban haciendo entrevistas con dueños de los tianguis en el mercado Tepito. Para los que no conocen la Ciudad de Mexico esta zona es conocida por su alto nivel de crimen y lo que voy a llamar 'comercio informal'.

En esto, le preguntan a una dueña qué le parece el presidente actual Peña Nieto, y responde con una respuesta más o menos así.

> eeeeh, le faltan todavía tamaños

¿Qué quiere decir 'le faltan tamaños' ?

¿Que le falta meterse en lo que hace? ¿Le faltan detalles? ¿Le falta agresividad en su política?

Comment: Yo entenderia como que no tiene dominio de la situación, que le falta todavía para estar a la altura de su puesto como presidente... es lo que entenderia en esa situación.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La expresión `le faltan tamaños` se utiliza mucho en la jerga política para indicar que a cierta persona `le faltan agallas`, le falta valor, le falta coraje y en una forma mas coloquial(y vulgar) se dice que `le faltan tanates`(testículos) para hacer algo en específico. En el caso que citas, se entiende que esa persona cree que a Enrique Peña Nieto le faltan agallas para enfrentarse a los comerciantes del barrio de Tepito tan afamado por sus altos índices de delincuencia.

En un sentido mas general se entiende que una persona a la que le faltan tamaños es aquella que `no da la talla` o no cumple con las expectativas para una función específica.

Comment: +1 Sí, creo que la respuesta es correcta. Pero vale remarcar que de manera canónica es un eufemismo para "Le faltan tamaños huevos"; *tamaños* está aquí por *grandes*, aunque su uso no es común.

Comment: También se dice _no da el ancho_.